# Visual Studio database schema compare is very slow

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2017, comparison

We've been using Visual Studio 2017's SQL Server Schema Comparison for all our (SQL Server 2016) migrations and deployments.

However, recently, it has become very slow, taking hours to process. If we uncheck the "Tables" object, it goes quickly. But when tables are checked, it is stuck on "Initializing comparison..." for ages.

I've not been able to find anything online that has helped us. Any ideas?

[Initializing comparison...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlQru.png)

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue?

Comment: Not an answer, but a refiend (more concise) question: Is there a way to optimize the Data Tools Schema comparison process? Excluding tables in a DB/schema comparison, to me, seems nearly pointless, since most of the changes you're bound to track down will be/are related to actual tables that hold real data, not some ethereal logical views that ultimately rely on physical tables. So disabling that is like certifying that a mountain bike is "OK", IF you disable testing it on muddy terrain.

Answer (score 7):

What seemed to work for us is that if you excluded tables (in Schema Compare Options --> Object types --> Application-scoped -- >  Tables), it runs quickly.

After its runs initially, you can compare again with tables selected, and its fine.

With the exception of this, the Visual Studio database Schema Compare is an awesome tool.

Comment: I have never found this to be a great tool.  It barely functions at best, at worst it has been plagued by bugs since its creation.  The update scripts it generates take a very long time to build, and fail more than half the time.
I use the tool to compare a db, but then do the changes manually as that ends up being faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSSQL Server Management Studio's own comparison or use one of these tools:

https://www.agile-code.com/blog/choose-your-sql-server-schema-comparison-tool/

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mikail. Unfortunately, MSSQL Server Management Studio's own comparison is what is running so slowly. It has been a great tool in the past, but now it just chugs along. I was hoping there would be a setting or something that could be tweaked.
I'll definitely check out some of the other tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem and I was able to find a solution.
Query starting with `SELECT * FROM (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME([o].[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName],` from `[sys].[spatial_indexes]` and other tables had suboptimal plan and was running for hours, causing VS to timeout and retry.
Plan guide included below solved the problem for me.

Because VS sends all queries in one batch during 1st attempt to get results plan guide will not kick in. After query times out, VS will retry this query in its own batch and plan guide will be applied.
To speed up the process even more and don't wait for time out you can kill VS session when it is stuck on this query and force retry.

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide   
    @name = N'VS Schema Comp Spatial Idxs',  
    @stmt = N'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
        SCHEMA_NAME([o].[schema_id])    AS [SchemaName],
        [si].[object_id]                AS [ColumnSourceId],
        [o].[name]                      AS [ColumnSourceName],
        [o].[type]                      AS [ColumnSourceType],
        [ic].[column_id]                AS [ColumnId],
        [c].[name]                      AS [ColumnName],
        [si].[index_id]                 AS [IndexId],
        [si].[name]                     AS [IndexName],
        [ds].[type]                     AS [DataspaceType],
        [ds].[data_space_id]            AS [DataspaceId],
        [ds].[name]                     AS [DataspaceName],
        [si].[fill_factor]              AS [FillFactor],
        [si].[is_padded]                AS [IsPadded],
        [si].[is_disabled]              AS [IsDisabled],
        [si].[allow_page_locks]         AS [DoAllowPageLocks],
        [si].[allow_row_locks]          AS [DoAllowRowLocks],
        [sit].[cells_per_object]        AS [CellsPerObject],
        [sit].[bounding_box_xmin]       AS [XMin],
        [sit].[bounding_box_xmax]       AS [XMax],
        [sit].[bounding_box_ymin]       AS [YMin],
        [sit].[bounding_box_ymax]       AS [YMax],
        [sit].[level_1_grid]            AS [Level1Grid],
        [sit].[level_2_grid]            AS [Level2Grid],
        [sit].[level_3_grid]            AS [Level3Grid],
        [sit].[level_4_grid]            AS [Level4Grid],
        [sit].[tessellation_scheme]     AS [TessellationScheme],
        [s].[no_recompute]              AS [NoRecomputeStatistics],
        [p].[data_compression]          AS [DataCompressionId],
        CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN [ti].[data_space_id] = [ds].[data_space_id] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                        AS [EqualsParentDataSpace]
FROM
        [sys].[spatial_indexes]          AS [si] WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [sys].[objects]       AS [o] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [o].[object_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[spatial_index_tessellations] [sit] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [sit].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [sit].[index_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[data_spaces]   AS [ds] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [ds].[data_space_id] = [si].[data_space_id] 
        INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] AS [ic] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [ic].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [ic].[index_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[columns]       AS [c] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [c].[object_id] AND [ic].[column_id] = [c].[column_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[objects]       AS [o2] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o2].[parent_object_id] = [si].[object_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[stats]         AS [s] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o2].[object_id] = [s].[object_id] AND [s].[name] = [si].[name]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[partitions]    AS [p] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [p].[object_id] = [o2].[object_id] AND [p].[partition_number] = 1
        LEFT  JOIN [sys].[indexes]       AS [ti] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o].[object_id] = [ti].[object_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[tables]         AS [t] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [t].[object_id] = [si].[object_id]
WHERE [si].[is_hypothetical] = 0
        AND [ti].[index_id] < 2
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY([o].[object_id], N''IsSystemTable'') = 0
        AND ([t].[is_filetable] = 0 OR [t].[is_filetable] IS NULL)
        AND ([o].[is_ms_shipped] = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                        FROM [sys].[extended_properties]
                                        WHERE     [major_id] = [o].[object_id]
                                              AND [minor_id] = 0
                                              AND [class] = 1
                                              AND [name] = N''microsoft_database_tools_support''
                                       ))
) AS [_results];
',  
    @type = N'SQL',  
    @module_or_batch = NULL,  
    @params = NULL,  
    @hints = N'OPTION (FORCE ORDER)';
```